# How to work with large numbers when writing and reading a file?

Tags: c++, iostream

I have written a codes to write my data from one input file to another output file, I used to read all lines of my input file

```
while (!inputfile.eof())
```

but in my output file, the last line is missing. So I would like to know, how to prevent this error?

My second question is: for writing data into file, I used

```
Outputfile.write((char*)&a,sizeof(double));
Outputfile.write((char*)&b,sizeof(double));
```

here a = 289814.150 and b = 4320978.613 but in the output file, it shows like

```
289814 4.32098e+006
```

(value of `a` is rounded and `b` value shows with e values) so what is the reason for this and how to fixed this problem?

Here i tried to use `cout.setf(ios::fixed);`, but if this works for data written on the screen, I don’t know how to fix this to write double data inside my file.

I want to write real values with 3 decimals only in my output file. Please anyone can help thanks.

Comment: The "problem" you're having with your numeric values is a problem in **whatever you're using to view them**.  You're storing the doubles in their native binary floating-point representation, they don't have "decimal places" but binary places, and the number of binary places is not adjustable.  You can round the numbers to the nearest thousandth (you'll still get the closest binary value representable in double precision though), but I'd suggest storing the full unrounded number and doing rounding only for display.

Comment: `while (!inputfile.eof())` is almost always wrong (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, based on comments, the intent here has (at least I hope) become reasonably clear: to convert pairs of numbers in text format to binary format, and be able to verify that the converted numbers accurately represent the originals.

There are a number of ways to do that, but the first thing to keep in mind is that no matter what else you do, converting floating point numbers to/from text (decimal) format can and normally will lead to some degree of inaccuracy. The problem is fairly simple: floating point is (normally) done in binary. This means it can only represent fractions in which the denominator is a power of 2 (or a sum of powers of 2). Decimal, obviously enough, uses base 10, so fractions can be composed of a sum of powers of 2 and powers of 5. Any of those that involves a power of 2 (e.g., 0.2) can *only* be approximated in binary -- pretty much like trying to represent 1/3<sup>rd</sup> in decimal.

This means your only reasonable choice is to allow *some* discrepancy between the decimal and binary versions. The best you can hope for is to keep the errors to a minimum. To test for that, what you probably need/want to do is convert the binary floating point back to decimal in the original format, and check whether it's *close* to the original (e.g., ignore errors in the final digit, at least errors of +/- 1).

The conversion itself should be pretty trivial:

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // checking argc omitted for clarity.
    std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    std::ofstream outfile(argv[2], std::ios::binary);

    double a, b;
    while (infile >> a && infile >> b) {
        outfile.write((char const *)&a, sizeof(a));
        outfile.write((char const *)&b, sizeof(b));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Verifying the data isn't nearly so easy. One possibility would be something like this (starting from the two files, one binary and one text):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 

    std::string text;
    std::ostringstream converter;

    std::ifstream text_file(argv[1]);
    std::ifstream bin_file(argv[2], std::ios::binary);

    double bin_value;

    while (text_file >> text) {
        bin_file.read((char *)&bin_value, sizeof(bin_value));
        // the manipulators will probably need tweaking to match original format.
        converter << std::fixed << std::setw(3) << std::setprecision(3) << bin_value;
        if (converter.str() != text)
            ;// they're identical
        else if (converter.str().substr(0,3) == text.substr(0,3))
            ;// the first three digits are equal
        else
            ;// bigger error
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That's much more likely to need some tweaking to work the way you want, but the general idea should be in the ballpark as long as you're sure the original numbers are all formatted consistently.

Comment: Correct solution for not getting the last line of the file.  However, aki is writing his numbers in binary representation and this is unaffected by `setw` and `setprecision`.

Comment: I used while command with getline(infile,line) but it doesn't work properly. i also tried with while(inputfile >> a >> b !=0) but i got same problem that last line of the file, i can not read.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yes -- but double in binary format will always store `DBL_DIG` of precision, so what he's asked for simply can't be done. He will want to use `setw` and `setprecision` when he displays the data.

Comment: @aki: You don't need `!= 0` in that condition.  You could try taking it apart, like this: `while(true) { inputfile >> a; if (!inputfile) { /* failed */ break; } inputfile >> b; if (!inputfile) { /* reading b failed */ break; } /* use a and b */ }`

Comment: yes Ben, i am writing my numbers in binary representation that's why i cna not use  cout with setw and setprecision. i wish to know any method to solve this. thanks

Comment: @aki: There is none. The best you can do is round the numbers so all but the first N positions (and possibly one or two of the last positions) contain zeros. If the numbers aren't too large of magnitude, you can do with by multiplying by 1000, calling `round`, and then dividing by 1000 to get back to the original value. If you want to store numbers with fixed precision, though, floating point probably isn't the best way to do it.

Comment: @Jerry: thanks for the your information, it's clear now. again I will explain my problem , i have a text file with numbers (double with 3 decimals) so first i read one line of my input file and then write it to binary (dat), this will continue until endof my input file.since i have to use this binary file for some further processing, i want to check my out put whether it is correct or not. for this I opend my output binary file and check it using:  fread(&a, sizeof(double), 1,pdatfile),fread(&b, sizeof(double), 1,pdatfile), then i show above decimal problem. so tell me the way to overcome this

Comment: @aki: I've updated my answer to reflect the new information you've provided.

Comment: @Jerry: Thanks i changed my codes according to your comments, it's great, my first problem is solved so i can read all lines in my first text file but i couldn't undestand how to implement codes for your converter part so still my second question is not solved.